# How do you read your very first message with someone?

Tags: message, facebook-messages

I want to read my first messages with someone on Facebook, but I think our VERY first messages were reported to be "moved" because we had so many. I am not sure how if it's even possible to read them anymore, but yeah. Please help! Or actually, maybe I deleted the first set of messaged we had. Anyway to read deleted ones? Most likely not, but still. Just wondering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are talking about PMs/Chat messages? If that is the case, Facebook does not archive very old messages. If you cannot find them in your messages box, then odds are they are irretrievable.